# How to invalidate ListView for new data when using ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

I am making use of a default listview in a fragment to show data that is being called from a URL. There is a SwipeRefreshLayout where the ListView is contained. However when I refresh, the old data is still in the listview and the new data is just added at the top of the list. Is there a way to invalidate the old data?
I have made use of a ListAdapter which is created from the SimpleAdapter class like so:
`ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newsItemList, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATE, TAG_OWNER}, new int[]{R.id.news_title, R.id.news_date, R.id.news_owner});`
                       `lvGeneralNews.setAdapter(adapter);` 

I have tried to make the adapter null or use the `invalidate()` method that comes with the listview. The adapter does not have a `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.
The `newsItemList` is an ArrayList that has the data from the URL. It is declared like so:
`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newsItemList;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the important is :
do you clear ArrayList> newsItemList when you get new data?
if u do
just repeat:

```
      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newsItemList, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATE, TAG_OWNER}, new int[]{R.id.news_title, R.id.news_date, R.id.news_owner});       
 lvGeneralNews.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: everytym i make it null before the call2the URL it gives me a null error.

Comment: and besides I should be able to click any news item and read but the newer ones are the only ones that return something the old dataset brings and error even tho they are in the same list

Comment: actually this is correct. I initialiased the object in the onViewCreated() method instead I moved that line to the method thats called upon refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `adapter.clear();` put it in the method that is executed when you perform a refresh!

Comment: ListAdapter does not have this method